# Snyk and Automatic Pull request

Tags: snyk

Does Snyk send PRs automatically when integrating from the SCM (Github, Gitlab...) ?

I tried the Fix PR with Snyk and that worked - now I'd like to automate the PR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snyk supports the generation of Fix PR (or Merge Request for Gitlab's naming) for all SCM integrations.
For all integrations, Snyk will generate auto Fix PR for `new vulnerabilities` found.

For Github and Bitbucket Cloud Snyk also supports the `fix of Backlog` (auto Fix PR for Open Source issues already in the code at the time of integrating with Snyk). it is not supported in Gitlab and Bitbucket Server at the time of this post

https://docs.snyk.io/scan-application-code/snyk-open-source/open-source-basics/fix-pull-requests-for-new-vulnerabilities

[image: Fix PR settings in Snyk]